# grok pattern to capture response body in nginx access logs

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, logstash, logstash-grok, grok

We are trying to capture below log snippet using `resp_body:\"%{DATA:resp_body}\"` but it only captures `'{'` We would like it to capture till the end double quotes. Please help to achieve this?

`resp_body:"{"responseCode":0,"responseMessage":"Success","totalOrders":10,"totalPages":1,"currentPage":1,"order":[{"order_no":"NYK-56395463-0544196","eretailOrderNo":"NAH43103202","masterOrderNo":"NAH43103202","status":"Shipped complete","remarks":"","grandtotal":"2822.600","createAtStoreDate":"10/11/2020 23:19:04","shippingpkgcount":"2","itemcount":"10.000","shippingaddress":"chapra ..sahebganj..sonarpatti Landmark: near libas mart","mobileno":"8789932063","is_giftwrap":"no","giftwrap_msg":"","giftwrap_charges":"0.000","cancel_date":"","udf1":null,"udf2":null,"udf3":null,"udf4":"COD","udf5":"10","udf6":null,"udf7":null,"udf8":null,"udf9":null,"udf10":null,"pickupLocation":"","extFulFillmentLocCode":"","shipdetail":[{"qty":"1","transporter":"Delhivery Surface","transporterstatusremark":"Handover to co-located facility","transporterstatus":"INTRANSIT","shipdate":"13/11/2020 08:42:05","updated_date":"18/11/2020 07:50:13","delivereddate":"","refereceNo":"NBL320254620","wh_Loccode":"NBL","wh_Locname""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GREEDYDATA` instead of `DATA` to match the complete string before the last quote. Use the below:

```
resp_body:\"%{GREEDYDATA:resp_body}\"
```